# How to add background image to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove background colour and want to add some image as background.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Title',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        cardColor: Colors.white70,
        accentColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Want to remove this bg color and add an image

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make like it?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Title',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        cardColor: Colors.white70,
        accentColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/bg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: null /* add child content here */,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Title',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/bg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          child: null /* add child content here */,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and also don't forgot to add a assetfile in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).